# Что за компонент на плате?

Tags: электроника

Подскажите название и назначение smd компонента , стоящего в 12 v цепи питания видеокарты , на фотографии - SL
[image: Фото]

Answer (score 2):

Это smd inductor , катушка индуктивности (дроссель) для выравнивания помех, колебаний.
На выводах должно быть низкое сопротивление, если резист большой или обрыв то спокойно можешь зашунтировать, не очень важная деталь